# '[preposition] whom' vs. '[preposition] who' vs. 'who ... [preposition]'

Tags: grammaticality

> A1. **To whom** were you speaking?
>
> A2. **To who** were you speaking?
>
> A3. **Who** were you speaking **to**?
>
> B1. They asked **to whom** I was speaking.
>
> B2. They asked **to who** I was speaking.
>
> B3. They asked **who** I was speaking **to**.

A1 and B1 are formal English, but, as we know, one can replace 'whom' with 'who' nowadays.

I'm unsure if this replacement implies the movement of the preposition (*to* in the above examples) towards the end of the sentence—like in A3 and B3—,  or not—like in A2 and B2? If so, is there difference under this aspect between the case in which the sentence is affirmative (B2 and B3) and the case in which the sentence is interrogative (A2 and A3)?

Comment: You forgot “They asked whom I was speaking to”, which is perfectly fine — and a lot better than most of those.  Rearranging the *to* to go in front usually comes off as unnaturally stilted.

Comment: Yes @tchrist, but when "whom" was considered "standard" English one could not move the preposition: 'to whom' was grammatical, 'whom ... to' was not. However you can even with 'whom' nowadays

Comment: People have always used what you might think of as proposition-stranding in English.  And I perfectly well assure you that *whom* is still considered standard in many situations, the most common being immediately after a preposition — even when doing so is wrong.

Comment: @tchrist, I will verify this fact.

Comment: Unless the copy editor is illiterate, *"to who" won't fly, even these days. Only the ignorant and uneducated would accept that as grammatical: Editors who don't like "to whom" would most likely change A2 to "Who were you speaking to?" That's what I would do -- unless the sentence was part of a dialogue and the point of the sentence was to illustrate the illiteracy of the speaker, which it does subtly enough.

Comment: Anyone pompous enough to say _To whom were you speaking?_ wouldn't dream of saying _To who were you speaking?_.

Comment: @Barrie, since you are an expert connoisseur of the English grammar, I would like to know your own grammatical opinion in reference to the closure of this question as a duplicate of "How can one differentiate between 'who' and 'whom'?" I know you don't use to answer this kind of comments, but, please, do an exception in this case.

Comment: @Carlo_R. The first thing I must do is reject your description of me. I’m a dabbler, just like everyone else here. This site, like EL&U, operates on the principle that questions relating to a single topic, even if they concern different aspects of a topic, are best grouped together. I don’t entirely agree with that, because I suspect not many people will want to go over answers written months before. I personally see no harm in reconsidering a question that’s already been asked, even it involves a degree of duplication. But that, I imagine, is not the majority view.